# Change default Document Root path in cent os 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I have cento os 7 and installing php website and by default i have to upload code to /var/www/html but i want my code to pick from /home/magento.

How to rewrite Document Root path in cento os .

Comment: I'm just revisiting some questions, how did you get on with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands one by one:

```
chcon -R --reference=/var/www/html/ /home/magento 
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/magento/ 
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/home/magento(/.*)?" 
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs true 
chmod 755 /home/magento # important !!
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `DocumentRoot` directive in your `httpd.conf` (this should be found in `/etc`).

The file should contain a line like:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

Change it to:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/magento"
```

If you add more directories in different locations that you want published you'll need to start making use of [VirtualHost files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/)

Also, if SELinux is set to enforcing, you'll need to set the SELinux context of the directory to match that of your /var/www directory. To find out whether or not SELinux is in operation use:

```
getenforce
```

If the output is "permissive" then it's not enforcing.

If the output is "enforcing" then it's enforcing.

In order to change the context of the directory and its contents run the following:

```
semanage -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/home/magento(/.*)?"
```

Now when you run `ls -dZ /home/magento` the "httpd_sys_content_t" context should be present in the output.

You will likely also have to set an SELinux boolean to allow publishing home dirs. To do this use:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs true
```

Note: the apache user will also need permissions to read the directory's contents.

Comment: i had changed documentroot to /home/magento and still website is not picking from /home/magento

Comment: Have you checked if SELinux is enforcing?

Comment: i didnt undersand what to do with SELinux is set to enforcing. i had checked getenforce it outputs enforcing

Comment: its enforcing...

Comment: Edited my answer with some more info.

Comment: i got command not found semanage  issue

Comment: looking into the issue for installing semanage

Comment: `yum -y install policycoreutils-python`